# Align the text vertically centered in the cell of Table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am new to latex. I am trying to make a table in such a way that the text in the cell should be centered vertically.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0.2in,
            left=1in,
            right=1in,
            top=1in,
            bottom=1in,
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
            
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm} |m{2.5cm}|m{5cm}|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{ballblue}\textbf{Range}&\textbf{lorem ipsum}&\textbf{lorem ipsum}    \\ [20pt]
  \textbf{lorems} &\textbf{454}  &\multirow{3}{1cm}{\parbox{5cm}{"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor"}}   \\[40pt] 
  \cline{1-2}
  \textbf{loremsas}&\textbf{456}  &   \\[40pt] 
  \cline{1-2}
  \textbf{loremsd}&\textbf{232}  &  \\ [40pt] 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{ballblue}
  \textbf{lorem ipsum}  \\[20pt]
  \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow} 280-560  \\[40pt]
  \hline
  \rowcolor{magenta} \> 280\\[40pt]
  \hline
  \rowcolor{green} \> 560  \\[40pt]
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

I have attached the output of the code. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to place the column that's currently third-from-left at the far left?

Comment: Unfortunately I need the table in this exact way.

Comment: Please do let me know, If i was not able to explain the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a suggestion using the newer `tabularray` package. I ignored the second tabular on the right-hand side since it doesn't seem to be related to your question (feel free to correct me on this).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    width=10cm,
    colspec={ccX},
    hlines,
    vlines,
    cell{2}{3}={r=3}{halign},
    row{1}={ballblue},
    cell{1}{1-3}={cmd=\textbf},
    row{2-4}={10ex}}
Range & lorem ipsum & lorem ipsum\\
lorems & 454 & "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor"\\
loremsas & 456 & \\
loremsd & 232 & \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

which gives this result:
[image: result]

Notice that everything about formatting is moved to the options of the `tblr` environment. In order, you have:

- `width`: total width of the table
- `colspec={ccX}`: declaration for 3 columns, c is for centered and X is for adjustable width (while respecting total width)
- `hlines`: draw all horizontal lines
- `vlines`: draw all vertical lines
- `cell{2}{3}={r=3}{halign}`: the cell on row 2 column 3 is 3-row wide and the text inside is justified
- `row{1}={ballblue}`: all row 1 has a ballblue-colored background
- `cell{1}{1-3}={cmd=\textbf}`: on row 1, content of cells 1 to 3 is processed through `\textbf`
- `row{2-4}={10ex}`: rows 2 to 4 are 10ex-high

There's one thing that I don't like, which is the last option. It'd be better to specify that all rows must be the same height, without having to specify any value, but I don't know how to do that (yet).

Comment: Thank you for the valuable feedback, I would surely try this method and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

- *Off-topic*: you need to cleanup your preamble:

  - some package are loaded twice even with different options
  - package `hyperref` should be loaded last
  - since `hyperref` load `url` too, you not need to load it again
- With `\\[40pt]` you insert space after rows, so by this is changed row height. Consequently text in row is vertical center in its heigh, but this is seem as that it is on top the cells
- The row height you can you increase by inserting of some struts of 40 pt height in rows, where are needed.
- both table is sensible to merge in one with one empty column

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0.2in,
            margin=1in,
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{5cm}| c |p{2.5cm}|}
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
  \rowcolor{ballblue}
\textbf{Range}       
            & \textbf{lorem ipsum}   
                    &   \textbf{lorem ipsum} 
                        & \cellcolor{white}{} 
                            &   \textbf{lorem ipsum}    \rule[-10pt]{0pt}{25pt} \\

\textbf{lorems}
    & \textbf{454}  
        &   \multirow{3}{=}[4ex]{
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor"}
            &   &   \cellcolor{yellow}{280-560} \rule[-20pt]{0pt}{50pt} \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{5-5}
\textbf{loremsas}
    & \textbf{456}  
        &   &   &   \cellcolor{magenta}{280}    \rule[-20pt]{0pt}{50pt} \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{5-5}
\textbf{loremsd}     
    & \textbf{232}   
        &   &   & \cellcolor{green}{560}        \rule[-20pt]{0pt}{50pt} \\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this table is far more simple writ using `\tabularray` package, similarly as is suggested @Miyase answer (+1):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0.2in,
            margin=1in,
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell{bg=#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Z}={1-3,5-5}{solid},
             vlines,
             cell{1}{1-3,5} = {font=\bfseries, bg= ballblue},
             colspec = {*{2}{Q[l, m, wd=20mm, font=\bfseries]}
                             Q[j, wd=50mm]
                             Q[c]                             Q[c, m, wd=20mm]},
             vspan=even
             }
Range   
    &   lorem ipsum  
        &   lorem ipsum
            &   &   lorem ipsum     \\
lorems
    & \textbf{454}  
        &\SetCell[r=3]{j}
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor"
            &   &\SCC{yellow}   280-560         \\
loremsas
    & 456
        &   &   &\SCC{magenta}  280             \\
loremsd
    &232
        &   &   &\SCC{green}    560             \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]